# Google apps script How can I extract all numbers under 550 from this array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, filter

Sorry english is not my first language. Ive been trying to filter out all numbers lower than 550 from this 2d array with little to no success. Im also very new to coding so pls detail what I might be doing wrong.

```
function SELECTVALUES() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sAvg = ss.getSheetByName("AVERAGE ARRAY");
  var arrayRange = sAvg.getRange('B3:AC30');
  var arrayValues = arrayRange.getValues();

  Logger.log(arrayValues);

  Logger.log(
 
    arrayValues.filter(function(x){if (x <= 550){return x}}));

}
```

/* what is intresting is that the array displays as number.0 (ex. 535.0,540.0, etc.) instead of simply listing it as 535,540,454,etc. */

Execution log
11:16:32 AM Notice  Execution started
11:16:31 AM Info    [[500.0, 505.0, 510.0, 515.0, 520.0, 525.0, 530.0, 535.0, 540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0], [505.0, 510.0, 515.0, 520.0, 525.0, 530.0, 535.0, 540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0], [510.0, 515.0, 520.0, 525.0, 530.0, 535.0, 540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0], [515.0, 520.0, 525.0, 530.0, 535.0, 540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0], [520.0, 525.0, 530.0, 535.0, 540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0], [525.0, 530.0, 535.0, 540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0], [530.0, 535.0, 540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0], [535.0, 540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0], [540.0, 545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0], [545.0, 550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0], [550.0, 555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0], [555.0, 560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0], [560.0, 565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0], [565.0, 570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0], [570.0, 575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0], [575.0, 580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0], [580.0, 585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0], [585.0, 590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0], [590.0, 595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0], [595.0, 600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0], [600.0, 605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 735.0], [605.0, 610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 735.0, 740.0], [610.0, 615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 735.0, 740.0, 745.0], [615.0, 620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 735.0, 740.0, 745.0, 750.0], [620.0, 625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 735.0, 740.0, 745.0, 750.0, 755.0], [625.0, 630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 735.0, 740.0, 745.0, 750.0, 755.0, 760.0], [630.0, 635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 735.0, 740.0, 745.0, 750.0, 755.0, 760.0, 765.0], [635.0, 640.0, 645.0, 650.0, 655.0, 660.0, 665.0, 670.0, 675.0, 680.0, 685.0, 690.0, 695.0, 700.0, 705.0, 710.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 735.0, 740.0, 745.0, 750.0, 755.0, 760.0, 765.0, 770.0]]
11:16:31 AM Info    []
11:16:33 AM Notice  Execution completed

Comment: Knowing that the array is a 2 dimensional array you could simply `arrayValues = arrayValues.flat()` before your filter loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just not agreeing with your data. Your code works if all of the numbers are in the same array, but your data has 28 different arrays. Your best bet is to filter through each array and add the value to a separate array.

```
  var filteredArray = []

  // For every element in the original set
  for(i in arrayValues){
    // Look for each value in that array
    for(k in arrayValues[i]){
      // Check if it is less than or equal to 550
      if(arrayValues[i][k] <= 550){
        // Add that number to the empty array
        filteredArray.push(arrayValues[i][k])
      }
    }
  }
  // Log your output
  Logger.log(filteredArray)
```